# F# - Argu produces error in Release mode but NOT in Debug mode

Tags: f#, command-line-arguments

I have some F# solution, which uses Argu to process the command line. Recently I made some changes to the code and some App.config files (basically I removed from all app configs all parameters, which could be passed from command line).

Then I started to get this error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Argu.ArgumentParser`1..ctor(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<System.String>, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<System.String>, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<Int32>, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<Argu.IExiter>, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<Boolean>)'.
>      at ContGenAdmProgram.main(String[] argv)

when I build the solution in a **release** mode.

And if I build in a **debug** mode, then everything works!

I wonder if anyone has seen similar error and if yes then where should I look to fix it.

Comment: Could you show us your `main` function so we can see how you're calling Argu?

Comment: Also the fsproj file.